# Controller/Action paths is not working on Azure php web sites

Tags: php, mysql, azure, routes

I hosted my php web site in Azure.Landing page is working properly.But all other pages is not working.Always having the 404 errors.I think I need to url rewrite in azure instead of .htaccess file in php.Can anyone tell me how do I want to do that?.
site Url : http://myfind.azurewebsites.net/

[path not find error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ee2fC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the rewrite module of IIS for this, you control the rules in a web.config file just like you would with .htaccess. The format is different however so you will need to create your rules in the correct format.

So you have two options, the first is to use IIS Manager to remotely administer the web instance, more information on doing that is in this [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/remote-administration-of-windows-azure-websites-using-iis-manager/) article.

The manual method using a manually written web.config can also be done, you can find some information on this on [IIS.NET](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module).